# How to change the user registration form markup

Tags: 7, users, forms

I want to change the markup on the user registration form that reads

> Spaces are allowed; punctuation is not allowed except for periods,
>   hyphens, apostrophes, and underscores.

and

> A valid e-mail address. All e-mails from the system will be sent to
>   this address. The e-mail address is not made public and will only be
>   used if you wish to receive a new password or wish to receive certain
>   news or notifications by e-mail.

to something more friendly.

I don't think [String Overrides](https://www.drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) works with the registration form so I guess I need a custom module - `hook_form_alter` perhaps?

Comment: Yes, `hook_form_alter()` is the right option

Comment: Thanks - but I am not sure how to target the markup?

Comment: Off the top of my head it'll be in something like `$form['account']['name']['#description']`, but if you install the Devel module and use `dpm($form);` in your alter hook, you should be able to find it easily. If not just update the question, it'll be something easily solved

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by implementing [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) in your custom module:

For ex:

```
function MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id == 'user_register_form') {
    //dpm($form);
    $form['account']['name']['#description'] = t('Your Custom Text');
  }
}
```

To add Markup you should look into [theme_form_element](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/theme_form_element/7).

Answer (score 1):

The strings you want to change are the strings used for the #description properties of the *name* and *mail* form fields.

```
  // Only show name field on registration form or user can change own username.
  $form['account']['name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Username'),
    '#maxlength' => USERNAME_MAX_LENGTH,
    '#description' => t('Spaces are allowed; punctuation is not allowed except for periods, hyphens, apostrophes, and underscores.'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#attributes' => array(
      'class' => array(
        'username',
      ),
    ),
    '#default_value' => !$register ? $account->name : '',
    '#access' => $register || $user->uid == $account->uid && user_access('change own username') || $admin,
    '#weight' => -10,
  );
  $form['account']['mail'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('E-mail address'),
    '#maxlength' => EMAIL_MAX_LENGTH,
    '#description' => t('A valid e-mail address. All e-mails from the system will be sent to this address. The e-mail address is not made public and will only be used if you wish to receive a new password or wish to receive certain news or notifications by e-mail.'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#default_value' => !$register ? $account->mail : '',
  );
```

You could change those strings by using the [String Overrides](https://www.drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) module (which works for every string passed to `t()`, as in this case), implementing [`hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7.x) in a module, or implementing [`hook_form_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7.x).
In the first case, the module would replace every occurrence of the strings, while in the other two cases the strings would be replaced just in a specific form or when other conditions are verified. Since you seem to want to change those strings only when users register their account, I would use `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`.

As there users who have the permission to change their own usernames, which means the username is not set when an account is created, I would use code similar to the following one.

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  global $user;

  if ($form_id == 'user_register_form' || ($form_id == 'user_profile_form' && isset($form['#user_category']) && $form['#user_category'] == 'account')) {
    // The user is creating a new account or editing an existing account.
    if (isset($form_state['user']) && $form_state['user']->uid == $user->uid) {
      // The user is creating or editing their own account.
      $form['account']['name']['#description'] = t('Your new description for the name field');
      $form['account']['mail']['#description'] = t('Your new description for the mail field');
    }
  }
}
```

In this way, users who can edit accounts of other users (users with administrative permissions) would see the default description given from Drupal.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the [Better Login](https://www.drupal.org/project/betterlogin) module which can speed things along for you.

> Fancy login forms for Drupal :).
>
> Styling Drupal login/password/registration forms are a mission most of
>   the time because they form part of the theme... This module removes
>   that issue, it is slightly inspired by the way Wordpress login forms
>   work, and uses three page templates to change the style of the forms.
>   It is very simple to use, just install the Better Login module and it
>   starts working immediately.